# Does any boxing occur when passing an array by its interface IList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, boxing

I would like to know if boxing occurs in the following scenario:

```
int[] someNumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Foo(someNumbers);

// ...

private void Foo(IList<int> numbers) {
}
```

I was unable to find an answer already for this question, so apologies if this is a duplicate!

Comment: `int[]` is a reference type, so no.

Comment: @Lee Awesome thanks! yes that makes complete sense. If you promote this into an answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `int`s are value types, arrays are reference types, so `someNumbers` is a reference type. Therefore no boxing occurs when assigning it to an `IList<int>`. Boxing would occur if you assigned an element of the array to a reference type inside `Foo` e.g.

```
private void Foo(IList<int> numbers) {
    IComparable<int> nc = numbers[0];
}
```